# htaccess add remove trailing slash url to existing rule

Tags: .htaccess

I am using using htaccess for routing variables with slashes making a pretty url.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However I cant seem to prevent a trailing slash at the very end so the url ends without a `/`.
Can anyone help me add this rule to the existing condition please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your .htaccess as this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /myproject/table1/table2/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# front router rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you but this clears out the sub directory the project is in.  this is my current local url `localhost/myproject/table1/table2/sub-folder/detail/`  and it truncates it to `http://localhost/sub-folder/detail`

Comment: when i deploy this live getting an error `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: error: `.htaccess: RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code '308' for flag 'R'`

Comment: production is on apache 2.2 centOS

Comment: Ah ok then use `R=301` instead of `R=308` as that is supported in only newer Apache versions.

Comment: WOW, YOURE THE BEST!!